# C++ or C compiler that I can call from a program(DLL)

Tags: c++, c, dll, compiler-construction

What is a C or C++ compiler that is a DLL that I can call and compile a C or C++ program from through a DLL.
What I want to do is call a function through a DLL that I will use in my C or C++ program(since they both use DLLs) and it will compile the files that I listen in the method or whatever.
I just want a library that I can compile an exe with(or a .app, that would be nice).

Comment: You reference DLL, should I assume Windows or do you need *nix as well?

Comment: Do you want a compiler implemented as a DLL? Or do you want to statically link a DLL into your C++ application? Or...what *do* you want? The question isn't at all clear to me.

Comment: Do you really need a DLL version of a compiler? Why not write a function that calls 'popen' or 'CreateProcess' to invoke the underlying compiler instead? Just curious to know the use case. I would explore clang from http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#libraryarch

Comment: Could you please rephrase a little as I am struggling to follow your request. FYI a C/C++ program can have functions available through dynamic linking. I've only done it with assemblers, but I imagine (or rather expect) the steps in [MSDN's Creating/Using DLL](http://goo.gl/xTjNC) ought to work for projects that are executables.

Comment: I am up voting the question to bring back to neutral - This question rekindled my interest in developing cross referencing tools

Comment: Why do you need a function in a DLL?  You can invoke any compiler you like by executing its exe.

Answer (score 2):

From my little understanding of the question, your best option is Clang. I found the following links useful and have started learning it myself - to build a nice C++ cross reference tool to  replace my usage of gtags/cscope for C++ code

[Clang - library based architecture](http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#libraryarch)

[On using libclang through Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/)

[Clang - The guts](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a compiler like [lcc](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/).  If it's a comercial project they will probably provide you with a dll version...

Answer (score 0):

Clang is the first thing that comes to mind.  The second thing is [TaskGraph](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~phjk/Software/TGL/), which is nothing more than a template-based way of wrapping GCC (unfortunately, TaskGraph doesn't have a clear license; you'll need to talk tot he maintainers).